# Cannot set custom RabbitMQ Management Port "You've tried to set management.tcp.port, but there is no setting with that name."

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi, rabbitmq, raspbian, rabbitmqctl

I recently set up RabbitMQ (v3.7.8) on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, along with a simple .NET Core app to produce messages, and I am able to push messages to a queue using basic username/password authentication.

I wanted to change the default Port of the Management UI from 15672. According to the documentation, this can be done in the `rabbitmq.conf` file. This file didn't exist so I created it in the `/etc/rabbitmq/` directory.

I added the following line to the config:

```
management.tcp.port = 15675
```

However, when I start the app using `sudo service rabbitmq-server start`, it fails with the message:

```
09:57:56.390 [error] You've tried to set management.tcp.port, but there is no setting with that name.
09:57:56.390 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
09:57:56.624 [error]     management.listener.port
09:57:56.624 [error]     management.rates_mode
09:57:56.624 [error]     management.http_log_dir
09:57:56.624 [error] Error generating configuration in phase transform_datatypes
09:57:56.624 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: management.tcp.port
```

I don't understand this, because the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#single-listener-port) says this setting is valid. I then tried to set `management.listener.port` as per the suggestion in the error and this worked OK.

Is this just the documentation being out of date?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/yompN9AQ31c/discussion

Answer (score 2):

As in the link in the Luke Bakken's comment, if you don't enable rabbitmq_management and there is `management.tcp.port` parameters in config file, there will be a problem and rabbitmq won't start. This plugin is not enabled by default, you have to enable manually.

You can check the list of plugins: `rabbitmq-plugins list`
Should see:

```
[E ] rabbitmq_management               3.7.10
```

If you don't see with start **E**, use `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` to enable management plugin